# How to format input in C

Tags: c, input

I need help figuring out how to take input in specific format in C
`{1,2,3,4}`// that is right input - numbers in {} separated by comma.

```
 znamky = (int*) malloc (n * sizeof(int)); // I allocate memory here
    if (znamky == NULL)                   
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    printf("Pocty bodu:\n"); 
    scanf("%c",&overeni[0]); // here I check if the first character is {; if not I exit program
    if (overeni[0]!=zavorka[0]) 
    {
        printf("Nespravny vstup.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    while (scanf("%d",&znamky[count])!=EOF) //here I continue loading numbers, and char fight
    {                                       //if the character after number is "," i load another 
       if (scanf("%c",&znaminko[0])==1)     //number, if it is "}"I exit the while cycle   
        {                                   // else I exit the program
            if (znaminko[0]==carka[0])  // if equals ","
                {
                    printf("sdf\n");
                    count++;
                    if (count==n) // if I run out of memory I allocate more
                    {
                        n = n*2;
                        znamky = (int*) realloc (znamky, n * sizeof(int) + 4);
                    }
                    continue;
                }
            if (znaminko[0]==zavorka2[0]) // if equals "}"
                count++;
                printf("utikam\n");
                break;
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("Nespravny vstup\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    printf("%d ",count); //here I just print length of my array
    printArray(znamky,count); 

    free(znamky);
    return 0;
```

My problem is this: when I run the code and give it right input, it works just fine, but if I for example input {2 and press enter it thinks, that the input is equal "}"and exits the cycle. Why does it think that? Above when I compare char to "{" it seems to be working fine...
Also any tips on how to improve the code are welcome, I am still new to programming so I don't see all the obvious mistakes.
Thanks a lot.

My problem is this: when I run the code and give it right input, it works just fine, but if I for example input {2 and press enter it thinks, that the input is equal "}"and exits the cycle. Why does it think that? Above when I compare char to "{" it seems to be working fine...

Also any tips on how to improve the code are welcome, I am still new to programming so I don't see all the obvious mistakes.

Comment: Change all `scanf("%c", ...)` to `scanf(" %c", ...)` If you use your current code and print the character you read then you will see why it's a problem.

Comment: Also, `while (scanf("%d", ...) != EOF)`, I can easily turn that into an infinite loop by simply entering a single non-digit character. You need e.g. `while (scanf("%d", ...) == 1)` instead. Or read whole lines with e.g. `fgets` and then use `strtol` or `sscanf` to parse the input.

Comment: Matouš Kovář, "tips on how to improve the code" --> Do not use `scanf()`.  Use `fgets()` to read user input.

Answer (score 2):

> but if I for example input {2 and press enter it thinks, that the input is equal "}"

The problem is here:

```
        if (znaminko[0]==zavorka2[0]) // if equals "}"
            count++;
            printf("utikam\n");
            break;
```

it should be:

```
        if (znaminko[0]==zavorka2[0]) // if equals "}"
        {
            count++;
            printf("utikam\n");
            break;
        }
```